# Disable touchpad on Thinkpad

Tags: windows, touchpad, thinkpad

I have a refurbished Thinkpad with an UltraNav "pointing device" installed as touchpad. I've tried disabling it through "device manager" but the "disable" option is disabled. Is there any way to temporarily disable it without uninstalling it?

Comment: `rmmod psmouse` if you use a USB mouse

Answer (score 1):

On my own Lenovo, it is possible to disable either the TrackPoint or the TouchPad (or both) by going to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Mouse > UltraNav.